# Oracle GoldenGate SqlExec Error

Tags: oracle, goldengate

I've recently intertied some Legacy code and was provide no documentation. I'm trying to understand where the issue is.

### Problem

My Golden Gate replicats abend atleast once a week while trying to load data into target DB.
It usually abends when attempting to load data into the below table: "table3"
Here's an example of the configuration from the replicat prm file:

### Config

```
MAP source.table3,   TARGET dest.table3, &
SQLEXEC (SPNAME dbo.tokenize,  &
ID Lookup2, &
PARAMS (KeyIn = key, &
        Id = ID, &
        tieBreakerIn =  TIEBREAKER)), &
COLMAP (usedefaults, &
ACTION_LEVEL_KEY = lookup2.actionLevelKeyOut, &
SD_TIEBREAKER = Lookup2.tieBreakerOut);
```

### ERROR

When the replicat encounters certain records the replicat abends and I see this error in the logs:

*Error in SQLEXEC Clause, id Lookup2: Invalid parameter name: KeyIn.*

### Help Needed

This seems like a pretty generic error message so, where is this error occurring? Does the error occur because of an error during the stored procedure execution? Or is it that after the stored procedure execution it didn't like the KeyIn parameter value it was trying to insert into the DB. Or is it because it didn't like the originally provided "key" Value? This is a new technology, so any guidance would be appreciated.